# efecto hover en imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Estoy armando una galería con imágenes donde la imagen tiene un efecto de `hover` al pasar el mouse por encima, además del texto en el hover quisiera que aparezca un bordeado a la derecha y abajo del texto, osea `right` y `bottom`, como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   margin-left:150px;
   
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    2;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         2;
   column-gap:           0px;
   
}
#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
 
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.3;           
}
a.darken span{
    visibility:hidden; 
    font-size:16px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      line-height: 100%;
}
a.darken:hover span{color:#fff; visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<section id="photos">
  <a href="/portfolio/test1.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY ONE</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test2.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY TWO</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test3.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY THREE</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test4.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERT FOUR</span></a>
</section>
```

Comment: El bordeado lo quieres en el texto o en todo el contenedor de la imagen como tal ? Explícate mejor por favor

Comment: Seria el bordeado para la caja del texto en el hover  @CamiloVasquez

Comment: Puedes agregar algún ejemplo en imagen o algo así, no me queda clara la definición de "bordeado"

Comment: Ahí edite la pregunta. @CamiloVasquez

Comment: @MarianoFranco, revisa el CSS, porque en la pregunta parece estar faltando el nombre del primer estilo.

Answer (score 4):

El efecto que deseas lo puedes obtener con los [Pseudo-elementos After & Before](http://librosweb.es/libro/css_avanzado/capitulo_3/pseudo_elementos.html) aplicándolos de la siguiente manera:

```
a.darken:hover:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: white;
}

a.darken:hover:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 85%;
  width: 3px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: white;
}
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

```css
/* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   margin-left:150px;
   
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    2;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         2;
   column-gap:           0px;
   
}
#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
 
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a.darken:hover:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: white;
}

a.darken:hover:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 85%;
  width: 3px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: white;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.3;           
}
a.darken span{
    visibility:hidden; 
    font-size:16px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      line-height: 100%;
}
a.darken:hover span{color:#fff; visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<section id="photos">
  <a href="/portfolio/test1.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY ONE</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test2.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY TWO</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test3.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY THREE</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test4.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERT FOUR</span></a>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias Camilo es exactamente lo que quería.

Comment: @MarianoFranco me alegra que te sirviera, te invito a que consideres marcar como aceptada la respuesta para que sea de ayuda a los próximos desarrolladores que depronto tengan la misma inquietud, saludos !

Comment: en donde se pone?

Comment: Puedes ver que la respuesta en la parte superior izquierda tiene dos flechas una para votar positivo y la otra para votar negativo, debajo de ambas flechas hay un check en opacidad simplemente dale click y se pondrá verde, con esto aceptas la respuesta, te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio